# GetSmoObject Error: Attempt to retrieve data for object failed for ManagedCompter

Tags: powershell, .net-client-profile

I am trying to write a PowerShell script that will enable the TCP/IP and Named Pipes Server Protocols, but my server is unable to find them. Here is the code I am using to connect to the protocols.

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo")
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlWmiManagement")

$wmi = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer')
$uri = "ManagedComputer[@Name='<computer_name>']/ ServerInstance[@Name='MSSQLSERVER']/ServerProtocol[@Name='Tcp']"
$Tcp = $wmi.GetSmoObject($uri)
$Tcp.IsEnabled = $true
$Tcp.Alter()
```

The problem comes from the GetSmoObject cmdlet, which I get the following error:

[image]

When I run GetSmoObject with my $uri variable set to the following:

```
$uri = "ManagedComputer[@Name='<computer_name>']"
```

I get the following results:

[image]

My server isn't able to find the Server Instance or the Client Protocols, even though I know they exist.

[image]

Does anyone know how to setup my server so it can detect both Server Protocols that I need to update?

Answer (score 4):

Yea, use the "Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlWmiManagement" namespace:

`[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlWmiManagement") | Out-Null`

You'll create a new "machine" level object of type ManagedComputer. That will contain all the instances on that machine:

```
$machine = New-Object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer' -ArgumentList 'deezNutz'
$machine.ServerInstances.ServerProtocols | Select DisplayName, State, IsEnabled
```

Just keep in mind, `ServerInstances` is a collection of instances. If the machine hosts multiple instances, you'll need to reference the one you want. To keep it simple, I'm assuming the machine has a single default instance.

Now, if you want to disable to protocol. Just set the property to `$False` and bounce the instance.

```
$machine.ServerInstances.ServerProtocols.Item(0).IsEnabled = $True
```

You can cycle the instance via `Restart-Service`.

Comment: I get an error at your $machine.ServerInstances.ServerProtocols cmdlet that says "SQL Server WMI provider is not available on <COMPUTER NAME>".

Comment: This could be a bunch of things. I hate to say but I don't have anywhere near enough info to venture a guess. I'd google around.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few really good commands in this module from dbatools.

Hopefully this will get you started

client protocol settings:
https://dbatools.io/functions/get-dbaclientprotocol/

server protocol settings: https://dbatools.io/functions/get-dbaserverprotocol/

Comment: Are there any solutions where I don't have to download the module from online? My script is going to be used on multiple servers, so I want to see if there are commands that readily available to me first.

Comment: Based on the module on line you probably could get these three scripts from github and have most if not all of what you need for this: https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools/blob/master/functions/Get-DbaServerProtocol.ps1 https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools/blob/master/functions/Get-DbaCmObject.ps1
https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools/blob/master/functions/Resolve-DbaNetworkName.ps1

Comment: or as an alternative you could download this on a desktop and pull out what you need to get to your solution:   find-module dbatools | save-module -Path c:\temp